# Javascript Calling Current Function Again After Handling Error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, callback

I've got multiple Javascript functions that make callouts to a REST API. Ocassionally a call can be made where the current session has expired and the API returns an error to that effect. Rather than have each of these handle the error and re-authenticate it seems like it'd be better to have a single error handling function, but to do that I need to be able to trigger the original call again.

Below is some pseudocode for the general idea... it's assuming the only error that can happen is a timeout.

```
function responseHandler(args)
{
    return function(result)
    {
        if(result.sessionExpired)
        {
            // re-authenticate, if all good then call the original function again
            reauth(function(err)
            {
                if(err)
                    return;

                args.callee.apply(null, args);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // call the success callback
            args[args.length - 1](result);
        }
    }
}

function doSomething(arg1, arg2, success) 
{
    makeCallout(arg1, arg2, responseHandler(arguments));
}

function doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, arg3, success)
{
    makeCallout(arg1, arg2, arg3, responseHandler(arguments));
}
```

To my mind this definitely has some code smell going on... Obviously these needs some kind of check to ensure it doesn't get stuck in a recursion loop for one thing. **So is there a much cleaner way of achieving the same thing that I've missed?**

I could try and check the session before each request but that would double the number of callouts made which isn't really feasible in this scenario.

**Updated Version**

Splitting out the `success` argument into a named parameter helps clean things up, and I realised I can also skip the use of `arguments.callee`.

```
function responseHandler(cb, args, success)
{
    return function(result)
    {
        if(result.sessionExpired)
        {
            // re-authenticate, if all good then call the original function again
            reauth(function(err)
            {
                if(err)
                    return;

                cb.apply(null, args);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // call the success callback
            success(result);
        }
    }
}

function doSomething(arg1, arg2, success) 
{
    makeCallout(arg1, arg2, responseHandler(doSomething, arguments, success));
}

function doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, arg3, success)
{
    makeCallout(arg1, arg2, arg3, responseHandler(doSomethingElse, arguments, success));
}
```